# Change default image to randomly selected image from directory?

Tags: php, image, random

I'm scratching my head over this, on the site I'm working on if the user doesn't upload an avatar it will randomly use a default image. I would like it to randomly select an image from a directory (say 1-10 images).

Here is the code it uses to get the default avatar and default avatar thumb:

```
if ( !defined( 'BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT' ) )
    define( 'BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT', BP_PLUGIN_URL . 'bp-core/images/mystery-man.jpg' );

if ( !defined( 'BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT_THUMB' ) )
    define( 'BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT_THUMB', BP_PLUGIN_URL . 'bp-core/images/mystery-man-50.jpg' );
```

I think the biggest problem I have is that I need the random avatar image that's selected to be the same as the random thumb that's selected.

Any insight would be great :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how many avaters are there but suppose four then

```
$pics = array ('abc.jpg','def.jpg','ghi.jpg','xyz.jpg');
$picid = $pics[array_rand($pics,1)];
define( 'BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT', BP_PLUGIN_URL . 'bp-core/images/'. $picid);
define( 'BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT_THUMB', BP_PLUGIN_URL . 'bp-core/images/'. $picid );
```

if more then 4 then you should rename them and keep file name as 1.jpg, 2.jpg and code can be then

```
$picid = rand(0, 100); //100 = No. of images
define( 'BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT', BP_PLUGIN_URL . 'bp-core/images/'.$picid.'.jpg' );
define( 'BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT_THUMB', BP_PLUGIN_URL . 'bp-core/images/'. $picid.'.jpg' );
```

Comment: using `$pics[array_rand($pics)]` solves the unknown number of array elements problem

Comment: yup another great one

Comment: it should be $pics[array_rand($pics,1)].

Comment: I will give this a go and let you know how I get on :) Thanks

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow for array_rand() 1 is the default, you can, but don't need to specify it.

Comment: @Dagon i went through the PHP manual and it did not specified that but whatever thanks

Comment: it does `mixed array_rand ( array $array [, int $num = 1 ] )`